# SQL nested aggregate function AVG with Join statement

Tags: sql, aggregate, average

I have two tables, first table is called Movies, second table is called Reviews like so:

```
Table Movies: [ MovieID / MovieName / MovieYear] 

Table Reviews: [ReviewID / MovieID / userID / Rating / ReviewDate]
```

where columns are separated by the /

**I am trying to perform a query that will join both tables outputting `MovieID`, `MovieName`, `MovieYear`, number of reviews and Average Rating**, and I got the query right until I got to the average rating part. I am getting an error in Azure Studio:

> "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an
>   aggregate or a subquery. "

And my confusion is that with the average function it's supposed to compute the average for a single movie but I also didn't want to do two queries where with the first query I just leave out the average bit, get the rating for each and then in the second query then compute the average; I was wondering if there was a way to do this all in one query. Below is my query I have so far:

```
SELECT 
  Movies.MovieID, 
  Movies.MovieName,
  COUNT(Reviews.MovieID) AS NumReviews, 
  AVG(CONVERT(float, COUNT(Rating) )) AS  AvgRating 
FROM 
  Movies 
  JOIN Reviews ON(Reviews.MovieID = Movies.MovieID)
GROUP BY 
  Movies.MovieID, 
  Movies.MovieName
```

Comment: What is your RDBMS? Please tag it as no two SQL dialects are the same. Also, is there a reason not to use subquery - for appearance?

Comment: Good question, embarassingly I don't know. And I guess you're right maybe I can do that. Well my professor was suggesting to be as efficient as possible and I wanted to limit the queries, but..I guess subqueries don't count? So how would the inner query then look?

Comment: You don't know the database you are using? Describe the interface you use to make SQL calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT m.MovieID, m.MovieName,
       COUNT(*) AS NumReviews, 
       AVG(CONVERT(float, r.Rating)) AS AvgRating 
FROM Movies m JOIN
     Reviews r
     ON r.MovieID = m.MovieID
GROUP BY m.MovieID, m.MovieName;
```

This calculates the average rating, which seems like the most reasonable calculation for ratings.

Comment: Wow this is exactly it although I'm surprised it wasn't more complex. The only thing was that rating belonged to review table but thank you. So I guess the part I didn't understand was how average worked. So how does it infer what field to look for when summing up the ratings?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to explicit your `COUNT(RATING)` Because `Error` says really clear.. Aggregate cannot contain other aggregate expression in it..

```
SELECT 
  MovieID, 
  MovieName,
  NumReviews, 
  AVG(CONVERT(float, CountRating)) AS AvgRating 
FROM 
 (SELECT 
    Movies.MovieID, 
    Movies.MovieName, 
    Count(Reviews.MovieID) as NumReviews
    Count(Reviews.Rating) as CountRating
  FROM
    Movies
    INNER JOIN Reviews ON (Reviews.MovieID = Movies.MovieID)
  GROUP BY
    Movies.MovieID,
    Movies.MovieName) As Derived_Table
```

Answer (score 0):

is there a reason you wrote it as `AVG(COUNT(Rating))`? if you want the average rating just use `AVG(Rating)`

Comment: In reviews there are multiple MovieID that have ratings so I need to count those up and comptue the average

Comment: This is more a comment than answer.